# Userpoints: deduct points programmatically

Tags: 7, userpoints

Is there a way to programmatically deduct points from user points?

I want to deduct points from users if a certain "featured Item" field is checked when they create a new content, but don't want to deduct points from users that created content without "featured Item" checked.

Comment: Hint: You could also do this using the provided Rules integration. The advantage is that you can easily alter it (fo the example the amount of points or add another condition) without having to change your code.

Comment: Can rules check for cck field status in conditions?

Comment: Sure. It's a bit complicated but you can find a lot of tutorials and documentation about rules, for example the excellent screencasts on http://nodeone.se/en/learn-the-rules-framework

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use userpoints_userpointsapi and pass points in negative if you want to deduct.

example

```
    $params = array(
      'uid' => $user->uid,
      'points' => -5,
      'operation' => 'mymodule_some_operation',
    );
    userpoints_userpointsapi($params);
```

For more information http://drupal.org/node/993376  http://api.worldempire.ch/api/userpoints/userpoints-7.x-1.x%21userpoints.module/function/userpoints_userpointsapi/7-1

Comment: Every time I call that function I get an error. "Fatal error: Call to undefined function userpoints_userpointsapi()"

Comment: Strange. Did you enabled the module?

Comment: Yes, Its enabled.

Comment: Weird, I can access that function from my template but not from my custom module. how could this be happening?

Comment: @saadlulu Are you maybe calling it from outside a function? Never execute code outside a function, at that point Drupal is still bootstrapping and not every module has been loaded.