# How to grant User Points equal to the price of a Commerce Product?

Tags: commerce, rules, userpoints

I would like to grant [User Point](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) to product owner in amount of product price after a product is sold.

For this I defined a rule as below:

- Events: Completing the checkout process
- Actions: Loop (`commerce-order:commerce-line-items`)

And I defined a Rules Component as below:

- Conditions: Entity has field (Entity: `commerce-line-item`, Field: `commerce_product`)
- Actions: Grant points to a user: (User: `commerce-line-item:commerce-product:creator`, Points: `commerce-line-item:commerce-product:commerce-price:amount`)

But when I save component it generates this Error message:

> Data selector commerce-line-item:commerce-product:commerce-price:amount for parameter points is invalid.

How I can do that?

Comment: Why do you need this condition?

Comment: Probably the reason is that commerce-product is already out of scope as the checkout is completed(I am not sure). Try to print the value and check it once.

Comment: @Daniele are you sure that you want to grant points to the user who has created the product?

Comment: @subhojit777 Yes, for example to manager userpoints as user credit. I create a virtual product that, once bought, give me userpoint needed to buy real products. Sadly commerce_credits don't have flexibility and currency replacing like commerce_userpoints.

Comment: @DanieleNapolitano why do you need that condition? I see the question has condition in rule component.

Comment: @DanieleNapolitano also I guess you do not want to add shipping service price as userpoints to the creator of product.

Comment: You might want to check out [the Goals module](http://drupal.org/project/goals) since it uses [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules), as does Commerce, and could probably be glued together with a custom set of rules fairly easily.

Comment: @DanieleNapolitano I have answered your question. See if that helps. I am waiting for the bounty points :)

Answer (score 5):

At first I tried to answer your question using [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) and [userpoints](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints) module, but I saw that while adding **Grant points to a user** as action there is no such data selector for selecting the user who has created the product. I found the data selector for selecting the user who is the owner of order, but that is not your requirement. (That is why I clarified this in comments).

I found a module solution to your question. The module uses [hook_commerce_checkout_complete()](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!checkout!commerce_checkout.api.php/function/hook_commerce_checkout_complete/DC). From the hook page:

> Allows modules to perform business logic when an order completes
>   checkout.
>
> This hook coincides with the "Customer completes checkout" event. Only
>   business logic should be performed when this is invoked, such as
>   updating the order status, assigning the order to a user account, or
>   sending notification e-mails. Interaction with the user should instead
>   occur through checkout panes on the checkout completion page.

This is the coding of the module I designed:

**YOURMODULE.info** file:

```
name = YOURMODULE
description = Module description
dependencies[] = commerce
dependencies[] = commerce_cart
dependencies[] = commerce_checkout
dependencies[] = userpoints
core = 7.x
```

**UPDATE**
As suggested by [Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive), I have changed the module file so that this custom module will also work with multilingual sites.

**YOURMODULE.module** file:

```
/**                                                                             
 * Implements hook_commerce_checkout_complete().                                
 */                                                                             
function YOURMODULE_commerce_checkout_complete($order) {
  // Iterate through every commerce line item added in product.
  foreach (field_get_items('commerce_order', $order, 'commerce_line_items') as $line_item_id) {

    // Load commerce line item by line item id.
    $line_item = commerce_line_item_load($line_item_id['line_item_id']);

    // We do not want to include shipping cost in userpoints.
    if ($line_item->type != 'shipping') {
      // Load commerce product by product id.
      $product = commerce_product_load(field_get_items('commerce_line_item', $line_item, 'commerce_product')[0]['product_id']);

      // Create parameters.
      $params = array(
        'uid' => $product->uid,
        'points' => commerce_currency_amount_to_decimal(field_get_items('commerce_line_item', $line_item, 'commerce_total')[0]['amount'], field_get_items('commerce_line_item', $line_item, 'commerce_total')[0]['currency_code']),
      );

      // Grant userpoints programmatically.
      userpoints_userpointsapi($params);
    }
  }
}
```

Reference links:

[userpoints_userpointsapi($params)](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/userpoints/userpoints-7.x-1.x!userpoints.module/function/userpoints_userpointsapi/7-1)

[commerce_checkout API](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!checkout!commerce_checkout.api.php/DC)

[commerce_line_item_load($line_item_id)](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!line_item!commerce_line_item.module/function/commerce_line_item_load/7)

[commerce_product_load($product_id)](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!product!commerce_product.module/function/commerce_product_load/7)

[Userpoints: deduct points programmatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41236/userpoints-deduct-points-programmatically)

[commerce_currency_amount_to_decimal()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!commerce.module/function/commerce_currency_amount_to_decimal/7)

Comment: Great solution, that's going to come in handy. Might I suggest one small change? It would be better to use `field_get_items()` to retrieve `$order->commerce_line_items`, that way this will work with multilingual sites too

Comment: @Clive thanks for the suggestion.. but I have never used field_get_item() before.. I have to learn its usage and apply that in this answer. Need some time :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the previous answer, which requires custom code, you may want to try the alternative described below to get around that error message ...

Your question seems to be a variation (not a duplicate) of the question "[How to grant user User Points equal to certain field's value / calculated value?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85706/)". Similar to the accepted answer to that question, try to adapt your Rules Component like so:

1. Add these extra Rules Actions before the Rules Action in your Rules Component that causes the error:

   - <kbd>Set a variable</kbd> that corresponds to "*amount of product price*" (as in your question), which appears to be `commerce-line-item:commerce-product:commerce-price:amount`. Let's assume you name that variable **`price_amount`**.
   - <kbd>Convert data type</kbd> of that **`price_amount`** variable to *integer*.  Let's assume you name that conversion result **`amount_of_points`**.
2. Adapt your existing Rules Action (in that Rules Component) so that the number of user points to be granted uses this (calculated + converted) **`amount_of_points`**.

PS 1: Such "Convert data type" is simply a matter of how Rules works (by design), so it's not to be considered as a bug either ...

PS 2: I assume your question is about D7.