# How to grant user User Points equal to certain field's value / calculated value?

Tags: 7, rules, userpoints

I've a content type 'Content' with the field 'Value' (an integer). Every time a **Content has been published**, I'd like to **grant the Content's author some User Points, equal to the value in the 'Value' field**.

I tried solving the first part of my problem with the Rules module like this:

```
*Event: A node has been published

*Conditions: Content is of type 'Content'

*Actions: Grant points to a user: ...
```

However, it's impossible to pick `node:field-value` in the Points section. I also tried:

```
*Event: A node has been published

*Conditions: Content is of type 'Content'

*Actions:

 - Calculate a value: `[node:field-value]` "+" 0. (Variable name = result)

 - Grant points to a user: ...
```

But then, the variable 'result' is not available. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution! I completed the second scenario (the amount of User Points is calculated) successfuly! Apparently, the User Points module didn't know that the calculation was an integer. Therefore, I had to add an extra action **Convert data type**: *Target type: Integer, Value to convert: [result], Rounding behavior: Always down*. I called it 'total' and granted the user this amount of User Points.

Answer (score 0):

Same you can achieve using the **[Userpoint module](https://drupal.org/project/userpoints)**: userpoint module provides an API for users to gain or lose points for performing certain actions on your site.

The User Points and userpoints_basic modules provide the ability for users to gain points when they perform certain actions, such as:

- posting a node (different points can be awarded for different
  node types, e.g. page, story, forum, image, ...etc.)
- posting a comment
- moderating a comment

When the nodes or comments are deleted the previously gained points are subtracted. If a node or comment author is changed the points are transferred respectively.

The number of points for each of the above actions is configurable by
the site administrator and a transaction log is created for each point (similar to a bank account.

Uerpoints module doc: https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/userpoints

User point rules integration doc: https://drupal.org/node/873386

Link for configuring the `rules` as per your requirement: https://drupal.org/node/874390

Comment: I thought my question made clear that I'm already using the User Points module. As far as I know, gained points aren't substracted automatically after deleting content and points aren't transferred when the author is changed. I had to set up some Rules to achieve this. Or must I enable these options somewhere? Also, your third link is a way to check whether the user has/had a certain amount of points after points were added/substracted from him/her. What I need, however, is a Rule to check if the added points themselves are more than 5. But I found a solution for this problem, using Rules.