# User Points Rules: Remove points (based on content type)

Tags: 7, rules, userpoints

I currently am using the User Points Rules module to grant points (both moderated and unmoderated) to users for signing up for content using the Signup module. However, for cases where the user cancels the signup, it doesn't seem possible to remove (through another transaction) the points.

The points aren't static (i.e. 1 point per signup and thus -1 point per cancellation), but are dependent on the integer value entered for the Events content type.

Suggestions?

Issue on d.o: https://www.drupal.org/node/2419721

Comment: Any feedback about my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be a variation (not a duplicate) of the question "[How to grant user User Points equal to certain field's value / calculated value?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85706/)".

Similar to the accepted answer to that question, use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module and try to create a rule with these Rules Actions:

- Calculate a variable that corresponds to "*the integer value entered for the Events content type*" (similar to what you wrote in your question).
- Convert the data type of that variable (to *integer*).
- Grant points to user (using the calculated + converted variable.

With that, the only thing left to do is to find an appropriate Rules Event to get this rule triggered.

PS: such "convert data type" is simply a matter of how Rules works (by design), so it's not to be considered as a bug either.